# Android Database returns null

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static  final int DB_VERSION=1;
    private static final String DB_NAME="SAMPLE.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="events";
    private static final String KEY_ID="sampleId";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE="sampleTitle";
    private static final String KEY_DATE="sampleDATE";
    SQLiteDatabase dbEvents;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampleTable(sampleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,sampleTitle TEXT,sampleDATE BIGINT,trash INTEGER DEFAULT 0) ");
        this.dbEvents=db;

    }

public Integer deleteItem(Integer itemId){
        Log.d("CURSOR:","IM HERE"+eventId);
        if(dbEvents == null){
            Log.d("CURSOR:","IM NOT INTIALIZING");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Where I'm getting IM NOT INTIALIZING

and in my Activity I'm calling as [When Delete Button is clicked]

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
} 
public void deleteItem(int Id){
    dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
    dbHelper.deleteEvent(Id);
}
```

I cannot perform DB operation where it throws to Null Pointer Exception.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create the **DBHelper** object and where you call the deleItem method please

Comment: yes, it would be interesting to see where you create it, what `DB_NAME` is set to, but most importantly, the error log, when it crashes.
you could be trying to create it somewhere you have no permission to.

Comment: @Drakkin I have edited the Code...Please check it

Comment: See DuZi answer, that's it !

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate` will be called, when you call `getWritableDataBase()` method with an instance of your DBHelper.

From the Javadocs for the method `getWritableDataBase()` with an instance of a class that extends **SQLiteOpenHelper**

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate, onUpgrade and/or onOpen will be called.

This means, that this code

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampleTable(sampleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,sampleTitle TEXT,sampleDATE BIGINT,trash INTEGER DEFAULT 0) ");
    this.dbEvents=db;

}
```

won't get you far. Since creating by calling `getWritableDataBase` or `getReadableDataBase` returns a SQLiteDatabase instance for performing SQLite operations.

So, from an Activity if you want to access your Database you have to do the following:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDataBase();
db.query("SELECT * FROM " + sampleTable);
```

Comment: @Drakkin I'm getting error [NullPointer Exception] at dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() line

Comment: in my Activity I called DBHelper  public void deleteItem(int Id){
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db1=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db1.delete("sampleTable", "sampleID" + "=" + Id, null);
    }

Comment: OK, to clarify things a little. onCreate in your DBHelper will be only called once. And that is when your Database is created.

Comment: sorry to make you understand clear... deleteItem is written in SqliteOpenHelper Class [DBHelper] to perform deleteQuery and it is called in Activity when Delete Button is clicked

Comment: yes ... DBHelper is called when database is created

Comment: I have updated my answer. Perform the query on the returned SQLiteDatabase object. If you want to perform it else where, you have to pass the object as argument.

And here is a nice tutorial for SQLite based Androidprojects: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: You are best setting the `getWritableDataBase()` as a global parameter in the `DBHelper`. Then writing **Reuseable** methods to get data from the database. Rather than writing (and duplicating) sql on the activties

Comment: @DuZi no luck same Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Alright. Again: When someone installs your app for the very first time and then calls `getWritableDatabase()` the `onCreate()` method will be called one time and then never again. That is what I mean by just once. So your `deleteItem(int itemID)` is pretty useless after being called for the very first time right after `getWritableDatabase()` has been called. It will always be `null` after the Database has been created